# Building EntityForm in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, 8, entities

I'm continuously getting the error: `Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: Incomplete or missing schema for mymodule.myentity.myentityname in Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->toArray() (line 248 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityBase.php).`

Here is how I'd implemented the EntityForm:

```
class MymoduleForm extends EntityForm {
  public function form(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $form_state['entity'] = $this->getEntity();
    $form['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
      '#default_value' => empty($entity->name) ? '' : $entity->name,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    ...
    ...

    return $form;
  }
  public function validate(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    parent::validate($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    //perform validation
  }
  public function save(array $form, array &$form_state) {
    $entity = $this->getEntity();
    $entity->save();
    print_r($entity);
    //throws error here

    $edit_link = \Drupal::linkGenerator()->generateFromUrl($this->t('Edit'), $this->entity->urlInfo());
  }
```

Doing a `print_r($entity)` shows two Object results: one showing all the values I'd filed up in the form and the other completely emplty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error has nothing to do with your form.

You need to provide a config schema for your config entity, see examples in node.schema.yml and many other places.

See also the [configuration schema documetation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1905070).

Comment: Could provide an example? or a Tutorial link? I'm quite new to D8.

Comment: @con_28 Giving a specific example isn't really possible as we don't know what fields your entity has. D8 is in alpha, so tutorials will be hard to come by. See `node.type.*` in core/modules/node/config/schema/node.schema.yml, `comment.type.*` in core/modules/comment/config/schema/comment.schema.yml for examples, after reading the docs Berdir linked to

Comment: Oh wait, there's a fully-fledged config entity example in the [Examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), that should show you what's needed

Comment: @Clive: Thankyou. That was helpful.